# Is Google Mock a good mocking framework?

Tags: c++, mocking, googlemock

I am pioneering unit testing efforts at my company, and need need to choose a mocking framework to use. I have never used a mocking framework before. We have already chosen Google Test, so using Google Mock would be nice. However, my initial impressions after looking at [Google Mock's tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies) are:

- The need for re-declaring each method in the mocking class with a MOCK_METHODn macro seems unnecessary and seems to go against the DRY principle.
- Their matchers (eg, the '_' in EXPECT_CALL(turtle, Forward(_));) and the order of matching seem almost too powerful. Like, it would be easy to say something you don't mean, and miss bugs that way.

I have high confidence in google's developers, and low confidence in my own ability to judge mocking frameworks, never having used them before. So my question is: **Are these valid concerns?**

Or is there no better way to define a mock object, and are the matchers intuitive to use in practice? I would appreciate answers from anyone who has used Google Mock before, and comparisons to other C++ frameworks would be helpful.

Comment: For the "redeclaring" part, note that `gmock_gen.py` can usually write the mock for you (given the header file and base class as input). Since C++ is complex, it may botch up, but that'll still cover most of the usecases so it does speeds things up.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I doubt that people here would use it. I could try, however.

Comment: What haven't already been mentioned is `googlemock`'s move-semantics support, which is mostly absent. You cannot use move-only types as arguments and you cannot use rvalue references as parameters. Unfortunately, as I know, google team doesn't have recent plans to update the project.

Answer (score 45):

I use it frequently.

It's trivial to do relatively easy things, and possible to do very difficult things - that's pretty much what I want from a framework.

The hardest part about writing custom Matchers (and other stuff) with Google's mocks isn't Google's mocks, it's C++'s template errors... they're close to impossible to parse.  I often write complex expressions by incrementally building a working expression from a few less complicated expressions.  That way, the template errors are easier to pinpoint.

I haven't seen a better option for c++ mocking, and Google's covers a lot of ground, so I'd suggest you give it a shot.

WRT the DRY principle, I agree the declaring the mocked methods is unfortunate, but without reflection, I'm not sure c++ would have much luck otherwise.  I'm near certain if there were a way, googlemock would be using it ;)

BTW: The [googlemock cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/CookBook.md) is a good reference.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I would definitely not have gotten that from the tutorial!

Comment: regarding DRY, see my answer to a question regarding managing boilerplate code generation for mocks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10260532/170521

Comment: I also decided to eventually go with google mocks.  Originally, I thought it's biggest disadvantage is that you have to explicitly write a mock class (with the DEFINE_METHODXXX macros).  However, I found out there is a python script included with the package that can generate the mock class for you.

Answer (score 23):

[Fake-It](https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt) is a simple mocking framework for C++. FakeIt uses the latest C++11 features to create an expressive (yet very simple) API.
With FakeIt there is no need for re-declaring methods nor creating a derived class for each mock.
Here is how you Fake-It:

```
struct SomeInterface {
  virtual int foo(int) = 0;
};

// That's all you have to do to create a mock.
Mock<SomeInterface> mock; 

// Stub method mock.foo(any argument) to return 1.
When(Method(mock,foo)).Return(1);

// Fetch the SomeInterface instance from the mock.
SomeInterface &i = mock.get();

// Will print "1"
cout << i.foo(10);
```

There are many more features to explore. Go ahead and [give it a try](https://github.com/eranpeer/FakeIt).

Comment: So what if your class doesn't have virtual interfaces? What if you design is based on policies and all of your code is templated? Can I use this framework then? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design

Answer (score 15):

Disclaimer: I wrote HippoMocks.

I can recommend looking at other mocking frameworks; there's a class of them that don't make you repeat yourself. They also do away with a new syntax for matching making your code read much more like C++ combined with English. Give it a try!

http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/hippomocks

Comment: Not needing to create a separate mock class is such a nice feature!

Answer (score 9):

I've been using googletest + googlemock professionally for a few years, and I definitely like it. One thing that hasn't been mentioned by others is that if you're already committed to using googletest then it makes a lot of sense to also use googlemock. They're fairly well integrated and shared a similar design style and philosophy, which is nice.

For example, googlemock provides `ASSERT_THAT()` macros which are super-useful, and coexist nicely with googletests' assertions.

I would caution you about abusing the power of googlemock, however. It can be *extremely* tempting to write very complex & powerful matchers that end up being totally unreadable. You just need to be disciplined when using it.

Some other thoughts:

- Googlemock can have a somewhat steep learning curve; the intricacies of matchers and expectations are not as straight-forward as you might hope.
- The concern about violating DRY is valid; it's annoying to have to manually define mocks when it seems like they could be easily auto-generated. It's fairly common for teams to write their own code generators that automatically define googlemocks for their interfaces.